# Problem with looping through arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to be able to navigate to the coordinates within the following table:

```json
{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        37.02255983,
        -1.43654556
      ],
      [
        37.08298464,
        -1.41777117
      ],
      [
        37.03893607,
        -1.44272341
      ],
      [
        36.96500169,
        -1.48081985
      ],
      [
        36.91303988,
        -1.47429887
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am pulling this data from a database and my first level looping results in the above object array.
My first level code is as follows:

```php
<?php
    $locations = \App\Model::all();
    foreach ($locations as $key=>$location)
    {
      $polygonXML = $location['polygon'];
      dd($polygonXML);
    }
?>
```

I want to end up with the coordinate key.

Comment: Post your current code

Answer (score 0):

The data you have is in the format of JSON, so you must first convert it to an iterable object in PHP using `json_decode()`, this converts it to an array and then a simple `foreach` loop can be used to go through every entry in the `"coordinates"` table.

```php
<?php

// Encode your JSON data from where it is coming from.
$data = json_decode('{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        37.02255983,
        -1.43654556
      ],
      [
        37.08298464,
        -1.41777117
      ],
      [
        37.03893607,
        -1.44272341
      ],
      [
        36.96500169,
        -1.48081985
      ],
      [
        36.91303988,
        -1.47429887
      ]
    ]
  ]
}', true);

foreach($data["coordinates"][0] as $coodinate)
{
    var_dump($coodinate[0] . ", " . $coodinate[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
string(24) "37.02255983, -1.43654556"
string(24) "37.08298464, -1.41777117"
string(24) "37.03893607, -1.44272341"
string(24) "36.96500169, -1.48081985"
string(24) "36.91303988, -1.47429887"
```